# Join table condition for between 2 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is it possible to join these tables:

Log table:

```
+--------+---------------+------------+
| name   | ip            | created    |
+--------+---------------+------------+
| 408901 | 178.22.51.168 | 1390887682 |
| 408901 | 178.22.51.168 | 1390927059 |
| 408901 | 178.22.51.168 | 1390957854 |
+--------+---------------+------------+
```

Orders table:

```
+---------+------------+
| id      | created    |
+---------+------------+
| 8563863 | 1390887692 |
| 8563865 | 1390897682 |
| 8563859 | 1390917059 |
| 8563860 | 1390937059 |
| 8563879 | 1390947854 |
+---------+------------+
```

Result table would be:

```
+---------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+
|orders.id|orders.created|logs.name| logs.ip       |logs.created|
+---------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+
| 8563863 | 1390887692   | 408901  | 178.22.51.168 | 1390887682 |
| 8563865 | 1390897682   | 408901  | 178.22.51.168 | 1390887682 |
| 8563859 | 1390917059   | 408901  | 178.22.51.168 | 1390887682 |
| 8563860 | 1390937059   | 408901  | 178.22.51.168 | 1390927059 |
| 8563879 | 1390947854   | 408901  | 178.22.51.168 | 1390927059 |
+---------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Is it possible?
Espessialy, if first table is result of some query.

---

UPDATE

Sorry for this mistake. I want found in log who make order. So orders table relate to logs table by created field, i.e.

first row with condition (orders.created >= log.created)

Comment: How are these two sets of data supposed to be related to each other? What's the logic you use to get the result?

Comment: I'm updated my question. sorry for this mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will result in a non-equi join with a horrible performance:

```
SELECT *
FROM t2 JOIN t1
ON t1.created = 
 (
   SELECT MAX(t1.created) 
   FROM t1 WHERE t1.created <= t2.created
 )
```

You might better go with a cursor based on a UNION like this (you probably need to add some type casts to get a working UNION):

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT NULL AS name, NULL AS ip, NULL AS created2, t2.*
   FROM t2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t1.*, NULL AS id, NULL AS created
   FROM t1
 ) AS dt
ORDER BY COALESCE(created, created2)
```

Now you can process the rows in the right order and remember the rows from the last t1 row.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to bind these 2 together.
No ID or other column exists in both tables.

If this were the case, you could join these 2 tables in a stored procedure.
At the moment you ask the first query, store the data in a newly created table, use it in the join to get your results and delete it afterwards.

Kind regards

Answer (score -1):

simply you can use **union**

```
select id, created from table_2
union all
select name, ip, created from table_1
```

Comment: What do you expect? The answer is not even wrong. You can try the query by yourself and see what happens.

Comment: The statement will not work (you have two columns in the first part of the union and three columns in the second part)

Comment: No, union all also requires both select statements to have the same number of columns. And besides: even if that worked, it wouldn't be what the OP wants.